# Spring integration change outbound reply channel using annotations in case of errors

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I'm using Spring Integration and I have this run-of-the-mill service:

```
public class SampleService {
   @ServiceActivator(inputChannel="A", outputChannel="B")
   public void process(String msg) {
      // ...
   }
}
```

There are also other services (`SampleService2`, ...) activated in a similar fashion. These are mostly chained (i.e. `SampleService` -> `SampleService2` -> ... -> `SampleServiceN`), except in case of errors and the question is about those.

While processing, I can run into an issue - either an exception from other services or just invalid data. I want each service to have its own outbound channel for reporting issues, so that I can customize how that is done. Some service might have different queues depending on the type of the issue. E.g. depending on the type of error, a service can:

- Send a request to a delay queue for later re-processing,
- Send a service to mail out the issue,
- Send to another service which might have a better logic to handle (but is slower)
- Stop processing this request in the middle of the chain

and so on.

I was thinking about changing the outbound channel or saying "stop processing". First, I'm not sure how to do that with annotations. I've seen that with xml config I can use header enricher, is that the way to go? If so, how to do with annotations?

Conversely, is this the best way to go or are there ways better suited from Spring Integration standpoint?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to put an inline gateway between each service; that way you can set a different error channel for each service.

It's easy enough with XML; a bit more tricky with annotations; however, the new [Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl) makes life a lot easier.

See [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/garyrussell/c969c00af9c9ce1a4d00) for how to do it with Java 8 lambdas.

I can create a Java 6/7 version if needed.

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks @Gary! Is this the recommended approach for these kinds of situations?